# how do i get the string inside the charfield in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I'm trying to create a user in my model by calling the create_user function but I want it to have properties of what the user enters into my model. How do I do this?

This is what I have:

```
class Person(models.Model):       
    #basic information
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)

    # FIX THIS!
    user = User.objects.create_user(name, email, phone_number)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [definition](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py). 
The signature of `create_user` is:

`def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)`

`username` is a required field

This has to be done in your view -

```
user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=name, last_name='', email=email, username=username)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. I slightly modified to: user_account = User.objects.create_user(first_name=name, last_name='', email=email, username=email) and I get an attribute error about stripping.

Comment: AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: What is the value of `name` ? - Your issue is resolved. This is just a sideeffect you need to resolve.

Comment: name = models.CharField(max_length=50) just like in my post

Comment: Oh.. are you calling `create_user` in the view ?

Comment: No. I'm calling it in my model. I'm not planning on using views. I just have a person model and I want to create a user with every person.

Comment: not sure if that is the right approach. I would not know how to achieve that

Comment: Would you be willing to help me with my design choices then? Do you have skype or email that you are willing to share?

Comment: sure karthik.ravindra@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `person` is a `Person` instance:

```
name = person.name
email = person.email
```

Comment: How do I initialize that instance? I get a Person is not defined Name error.

Comment: @MattM: Generally speaking, `person = Person.objects.create(name='name', email='email', phone_number=phone)`, but it's hard to say for your specific case without more information.

Comment: What information do you need to know? I'm using the default User model. My admin just registers a model and the admin associated with it.

Comment: @MattM: Can you provide the code sample where you're trying to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in the model class, shown in the original post.

Comment: Basically, my goal is to create a user with every person that is created, such that they can log into the admin site and eventually add limiting permissions.